# Parser exception for /FadeInOut/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android

I hope this error is in manifest file ,here i am placing the manifest file.error is showing at last line.
thanks in advance

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.sri.fadeinout"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: yes , i cleaned my project.

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse then afterwards cleaning your project again. Unless my Eclipse is being odd, I put your xml into my project and it didn't complain. Also, check if there is anything past the `</manifest>` tag. Maybe a stray `>` that you didn't copy here.

Comment: Thanks buddy ,problem cause : i declared </manifest> twice.
Thank you soo much..

Comment: No problem. Again like your last question, you may delete it, post an answer to your own question and accept it, or let me answer it and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you pay attention to anything after the `</manifest>` tag. Although the top (and what you post on SO) may be fine, if you have other things below this tag, Eclpise will throw an error (and with good reason, your xml is now malformed).